# getContext("2D") не работает

Tags: javascript

Только начал изучать JavaScrip.
Решил написать простую программу:

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvasid" width="300" height="100" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
    </canvas>
        <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasid");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2D");

        ctx.moveTo(70,70);
        ctx.lineTo(100,50);
        ctx.stroke();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Но браузер не рисует линию.

Answer (score 1):

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2D"); 
должно быть :
var ctx = canvas.getContext("**2d**");